# matplotlib inverting y-axis in 3D loses labels. Need workaround for this known bug

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib

There is a [known bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/570) that has yet to be fixed in matplotlib.

Consider this code snippet. By reversing the y axis, the ticks disappear and the padding on the z-axis is changed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim3d(0,1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0,1)
ax.set_ylim3d(1,0)
plt.show()
```

Does anybody have a workaround for this in the meantime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can bring your data to [0,1] range (or [yourmin, yourmax] where yourmin < yourmax) and then just change axis ticks labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import numpy as np

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    ax.set_xlim3d(0,1)
    ax.set_ylim3d(0,1)
    # setting ticks positions
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2))
    # setting ticks labels
    ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(1, -.1,-.2,).round(1))
    ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(1, -.1,-.2,).round(1))

    plt.show()
```